# How to implement automatic authentication using link in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to implement login using some link in spring boot.
for example, the url will be `http://localhost:8080/superlogin?token=323xs232sdfddgw3`
whenever user open this url in browser, will need to decrypt the token and get user id, then make auto-login as that user. This will need to be same with normal login after that.
I made normal login page and it works, but I am not sure for this link login. I am sure I need to do something in security configuration.
Can anyone advise me kindly?

Comment: How do you plan to provide user this token at the very first place? 
Usually when you provide some credentials this token is provided by the server in response and stored in the browser.

Comment: I will generate this token for each user on admin panel.  it will include user id as well.